# How to Encapsulate Transaction Pattern in Java

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, transactions

I'm trying to write DAOs for my database models using the transaction pattern like such,

```
    Session session = null;
    Transaction tx = null;

    try{
        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        tx.setTimeout(5);

        //doSomething(session);

        tx.commit();


    }catch(RuntimeException e){
        try{
            tx.rollback();
        }catch(RuntimeException rbe){
            log.error("Couldnâ€™t roll back transaction", rbe);
        }
        throw e;
    }finally{
        if(session!=null){
            session.close();
        }
    }
```

What's a good approach to encapsulate this pattern in a method with

```
        //doSomething(session);
```

as an argument to be performed as part of the transaction?  Sometimes I run a query, sometimes I operate on `session.saveOrUpdate`, etc.  I have many DAOs to write and this pattern of code duplication is bothering me.

**EDIT**

Is there a direct mapping between `session` operations and HQL (`saveOrUpdate`, `delete`, etc) so all I need to pass into this method is just a query?

Thanks for the insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might be what you're after

```
public void doSomething(MyQuery myQuery) {
    ...
    Transaction tx = null;
    try {
        ...
        myQuery.execute(tx);
        ...
    } catch (...) {
    } finally {
    }
}

public class MyQuery {
    public void execute(Transaction tx) {
        // run queries on transaction
    }
}
```

Either create a new `MyQuery` instance or a new `MyQuery` subclass for each query or set of queries you want to execute

Comment: Thanks for the response.  After thinking about it, there are certain actions that are performed using the session object like `session.merge()`, `session.get()`, etc.  Is there an effective mapping between those functions to queries.  This way I can completely extract all queries from session dependencies.

Comment: @Luke You can always change the `execute` signature to `execute(Session session, Transaction tx)` and have the "queries" execute the methods on the session object. If you want to keep the transaction and session parts separate, then use a `MyQuery` class with an `execute(Transaction tx)` method and a `MySessionState` class with an `execute(Session session)` method

Comment: Thanks!  I did some modifications, and I got it to work.  Wished there was something like Task like C#.